# jQueryUI slider doesn't work on WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, slider, jquery-ui-slider

I can't get jQueryUI slider working on Wordpress. I got the following HTML structure:

```
<input type="text" name="TPSP[numberOfPosts]" id="numberOfPosts" value="<?php $args['options']['numberOfPosts']; ?>" />
<div id="NOP_slider"></div>​​​​​​​​​​
```

And the following jQuery function:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var numberOfPosts = AdminPageOptions.numberOfPosts;
    $( "div#NOP_slider" ).slider({
        value:numberOfPosts,
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        step: 1,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#numberOfPosts" ).val( ui.value );
        }
    });
    $( "#numberOfPosts" ).val( $( "#NOP_slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
})​
```

But Wordpress doesn't show the `div#NOP_slider` as a slider and I can't use it. I tried also to deregister the WordPress-owned jQueryUI and to register a custom version of it which I downloaded from the jQueryUI website, but nothing changed. Is there a way to get it to work properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1st thing I would try is getting rid of the div from this line - $( "div#NOP_slider" ).slider({

Comment: I solved that, missed css was the problem.

Comment: cany you maybe answer HOW you resolved it and close the question as solved ?